# Position of edge labels in \Edge[label=e] in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-graph, edge

Here is a simple code I have, which enough of an example of what I'm looking for. I am using the `\Edge` command with label, as this  labels directly on the edge, which is what I am looking for. What I would like to know is how I can determine where it places the label, as it currently always places the label in the middle of the edge.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows, petri, topaths, graphs, graphs.standard}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
     \tikzset{vertex/.style = {shape=circle, fill=black, draw, minimum size=.25em,inner sep=1.7pt}}
     \node[vertex] (v1) at (2,0){};
     \node[vertex] (v2) at (-2,0){};
     \Edge[label=$e_1$] (v1)(v2);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The graph given by the code:

[image: The graph given by the code]

Comment: You might want to make sure that you test the code that you post, your code doesn't work because the `tkz-graph` package is missing, and because of the space between `]` and `(v1)` in the `\Edge`.

Answer (score 4):

You can set `style={pos=0.2}` in the `\Edge` options. The `pos` indicates the fractional distance between the two coordinates.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  vertex/.style = {shape=circle, fill=black, draw, minimum size=.25em,inner sep=1.7pt}
]
     \node[vertex] (v1) at (2,0){};
     \node[vertex] (v2) at (-2,0){};

     \Edge[label=$e_1$,style={pos=0.2}](v1)(v2)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```